# PC outgoing sound to a cellphone input

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, audio-streaming, cells

Instead of putting a cell phone near a PC speaker :

Is there a way to stream outgoing sound from PC (the so called Stereo Mix in Windows)
to a cell phone input (an iPhone for example) and then to a 3GP call ?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in college to annoy people in the dorms with funny sound boards. Calling people with a Mister Rogers sound board was always hilarious.

anyways, you can easily coble together a 1/8" headphone jack to a headset plug (with mic input) that is meant to plug into a cell phone. I'm not sure if there is a commercial product available but I know I made one in about 5 minutes with parts from radio shack.

Comment: lol.
I was wondering if there was any iPhone app for receiving the voice via Wifi/Bluetooth from the PC...

Comment: Not sure about an app, but you can use this http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/497342-REG/JK_Audio_DAP3_DAPTOR_3_Bluetooth_Cell_Phone.html if you have $350 to spend.

Comment: You didn't state anything about wanting an app. Can you even run an app at the same time as a voice call on an iphone? I owned a 3G for a while and don't remember this capability.

Comment: You could use a VOIP program on your PC, like skype, instead of the phone. I believe this would accomplish allowing PC input into your call.

Comment: Is there a way to use an iPhone as a modem and then use a phone software like Classic PhoneTools?

Comment: ...maybe you should research that. I'm sure a simple google search would turn up a plethora of answers.

Comment: this is what i'm doing lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but we need more details to know what to recommend.

If you are going to be using this a lot, you can use something like this http://www.buy.com/prod/jk-audio-daptor-2-dap2-wireless-phone-audio-interface-for-use-with/q/sellerid/22583914/loc/111/219845839.html

Depending on the phone, you can also sometimes just use a standard 1/8" cable.

Comment: I'm rather looking for a software for streaming the sound from PC and an iPhone application for receiving and streaming it into a regular cell phone call (in real time)

Answer (score 0):

The first half can be done with [Wifi2Hifi](http://www.wifi2hifi.com/), the second half isn't something I've ever heard of. Either use a second device, or turn the volume up so the microphone of the same iphone can hear what the speakers are doing (unless iOS mutes it for the call, which is likely).